# Can't convert simple python code to haskell

Tags: python, haskell, recursion

I'm trying to convert this to Haskell,

```
def longest_path(edge, edges):
    remaining = list(edges)
    del remaining[remaining.index(edge)]
    possibles = [x for x in remaining if x[0] == edge[1]]
    maxchain = []
    for c in possibles:
        l = longest_path(c, remaining)
        if len(l) > len(maxchain):
            maxchain = l
    return [edge] + maxchain
```

This is as far as I got,

```
deleteN :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
deleteN _ []     = []
deleteN i (x:xs)
   | i == 0    = xs
   | otherwise = x : deleteN (i-1) xs

longestPath edge edges = let
  remaining = deleteN (fromMaybe $ elemIndex edge edges) edges
  possibiles = [opt | opt <- remaining, (fst opt) == (snd edge)]
```

I can't figure out how to do the for loop with recursion. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: You don't need an explicit loop or recursion. "Compute something for each element in the list'. There's a built-in fuction for that called `map`. "Go over a list and update a value based on the previous value and the current list element". Another builtin, foldr.

Comment: @n.m. That `for` is not a `map`, because it keeps track of the best `maxchain` during the loop... It's more a `fold`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: This answer is written in literate Haskell. Save it as `*.lhs` and load it in GHCi.</sup>

```hs
> import Data.Ord (comparing)
> import Data.List (delete, maximumBy)
> type Edge = (Int, Int)
```

Let us have a look at your Python code and think of how the Haskell function should look like:

```hs
def longest_path(edge, edges):
```

Allright. We start with a single edge and a list of edges. Therefore, we should write a function with that type:

```hs
> longestPath :: Edge -> [Edge] -> [Edge]
> longestPath edge edges =
```

Now, what do we do in our Python code? Apparently, we remove our current `edge` from the list of edges:

```hs
    remaining = list(edges)
    del remaining[remaining.index(edge)]
```

Luckily, there is a function to remove the first occurence of an element in a list, namely `delete`:

```hs
>     let remaining = delete edge edges
```

So far so good. Now, `possibles` is just the list of edges with have the correct end-point:

```hs
    possibles = [x for x in remaining if x[0] == edge[1]]
```

That's easy too:

```hs
>         possibles = filter (edge `connectedTo`) edges
```

And then we look for the longest chain for all the possible edges.

```hs
    maxchain = []
    for c in possibles:
        l = longest_path(c, remaining)
        if len(l) > len(maxchain):
            maxchain = l
```

Since we cannot modify `maxchain` in Haskell, let's create all those intermediate paths instead:

```hs
>         paths = [] : map (\e -> longestPath e remaining) possibles
```

**This** is where the recursion happens. For every `Edge` in our possible edges, we create the `longestPath` of that edge and the remaining ones.

Most of `for` loops can be expressed as `map` and a following fold. The fold we will use is `maximumBy`, where we compare the lists by their length with `comparing length`:

```hs
>     in edge : maximumBy (comparing length) paths
```

We've used a small helper though, `connectedTo`. But that's easy:

```hs
> connectedTo :: Edge -> Edge -> Bool
> connectedTo (_,b) (x,_) = b == x
```

All code at once:

```hs
import Data.List (delete, maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

type Edge = (Int, Int)

longestPath :: Edge -> [Edge] -> [Edge]
longestPath edge edges =
    let remaining = delete edge edges
        possibles = filter (edge `connectedTo`) edges
        paths = [] : map (\e -> longestPath e remaining) possibles
    in edge : maximumBy (comparing length) paths

connectedTo :: Edge -> Edge -> Bool
connectedTo (_,b) (x,_) = b == x
```

Comment: This almost works, but it throws an Exception: List.maximumBy: empty list

Comment: *It prints the first few edges on the path but then fails giving the exception

Comment: @D.B.Cooper Err, sorry, forgot the empty case.

Answer (score 3):

That python code isn't really the best... I don't see the point of finding the index of `edge` and then `del`eting it... just use `edges.remove(edge)`.

In the same way in Haskell you can just `filter` the edges:

```
remaining = filter (/= edge) edges
```

Now, your `for` loop is tracking the best result so far. This in Haskell could be done by a recursive function using an accumulator parameter. However the pattern here is that of a `fold`:

```
foldr f [] possibilities
```

Where:

```
f c maxchain = let l = longestPath c remaining
               in
                   if length l > length maxchain then l else maxchain
```

You could modify `longestPath` to also return the length of the path and avoid the calls to `length`...

---

The complete code would look like:

```
longestPath edge edges = foldr f [] possibilities
  where
    remaining = filter (/= edge) edges
    possibilities = [opt | opt <- remaining, (fst opt) == (snd edge)]
    f c maxchain = if length l > length maxchain then l else maxchain
      where
        l = longestPath c remaining
```

---

As pointed out in the comments instead of `filter` you could use `delete edge edges` to remove just *one* occurrence of `edge`. This shouldn't matter if you are dealing with standard graphs, though.

Comment: Err, `remaining = delete edge edges` would be the same behaviour as in Python/OPs code. Parallel edges _might_ be allowed and thus shouldn't get removed.

Comment: @Zeta Noted, but it probably doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: Run-time will probably differ slightly, but yeah, there won't be that many parallel edges, I suppose.